# How do I obtain a new access token with a refresh token with Google OAuth 2.0?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, google-authentication

I am building a react-native app on expo. The app uses Google Drive APIs to create and write into Spreadsheets.

I use firebase to keep track of the spreadsheet Id and similar info in a database.

I would like to automatically ask for a new access token with the refresh token once the first has expired.

Looking at the docs I put together this HTTP call but it returns a 401 Unauthorized error...

```
async function getNewToken(refreshToken) {
  return await fetch('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      client_id: '<MY_CLIENT_ID>',
      client_secret: '<MY_CLIENT_SECRET>',
      refresh_token: refreshToken,
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
    }),
  });
}
```

What am I getting wrong?

Thanks in advance